# Laravel Ajax Upload image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, laravel

I have an issue in my laravel ajax application, I cant upload images/files through ajax POST. always return No.

I think the problem in AJAX, the upload without Ajax works very well

please, find below my code for uploading images.

```
ajax : 

    $('form[name="photoedit"]').on('submit', function (e){
        var res = $(this).attr('id');
        var str = res;
        var variable = str.substr(1);

        e.preventDefault();

        var pic = $('#u'+variable).val();
        var mur_id = $('#mur_i'+variable).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData($("#p"+variable)[0], pic, mur_id),
                contentType: false,       .
                cache: false,             
                processData: false,
                success: function( data ) {
                    ....
                    }

view : 

{!! Form::open(array('url'=> '/01/mur', 'method'=>'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'id'=>'p'.$mur->id, 'name'=>'photoedit')) !!}          

{{ Form::file('u'.$journal->id, ['class' => 'upload fileUpload', 'multiple'=>'multiple', 'name'=>'u'.$journal->id, 'id'=>'u'.$journal->id]) }}

{!! Form::hidden('edi_i'.$mur->id, $mur->id) !!}

{{ Form::hidden('mur_i'.$mur->id, $mur->id, array('id' => 'mur_i'.$mur->id)) }}

{!! Form::submit('Save', array('class'=>'btn ideng', 'id'=>'d'.mur>id, 'style'=>'border-bottom: 2px solid #2d9e36; border-radius: 0; font-size: 12px; padding: 3px 8px; float: right; background: #35b73f; color: #ffffff; margin: 10px 0 5px 0;')) !!}
```

{!! Form::close() !!}

```
controller :

if($request->hasFile('pic')){

if($request->ajax()){
    $avatar=$request->file('pic');
    $filename=time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($avatar)->resize(650,500)->save(storage_path('img/profil/'01'/mur/'. $filename));

        $edi_id=Input::get('mur_id');
    $user = \App\Mur::find($edi_id);

    $user->image = $filename;
    $user->save();
        return \Response::json($user);
}
}else{
return 'No';
}
```

Without the hidden field, it works very well.
exp :

data: new FormData($("#p"+variable)[0]),

Comment: try `return Input::all()` and check what the controller actually receives

Comment: where I add return Input::all()  in controller?

Comment: You can return it in the first line inside your function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="photoedit"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var forms = document.querySelector('form[name="photoedit"]');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formDatas = new FormData(forms);
    request.open('post','/yourRouteHere');
    request.send(formDatas);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {

            //Return message from controller here
            //Handle it

            }
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine for me. I guess it can help. Also what I noticed in your AJAX, I did not see the URL where you post your form.

I guess your AJAX should have looked something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your-post-url', //Notice this URL
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {new FormData($("#p"+variable)[0], pic, mur_id)},
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

In your controller access the input type file with name attribute in the HTML form

Comment: the url it's same of form url: '/01/mur'

Comment: You will need to specify URL in your `$.ajax` function because you use `e.preventDefault();` the default URL of the form will not work.

Comment: BUT it's work for me when I remove the hidden field. exp :

data: new FormData($("#p"+variable)[0]),